# categories ordering not as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a categories model with many categories, that has an attribute called tag.

A main category has a tag e.g 1
and a child category has a tag 1-1

so in order to show those categories one after the other in correct order, i order them by tag using the following

`@categories = Category.order("tag ASC")`

but for some reason let say i have tags,

**[1, 1-1, 1-2, 3,4, 10, 10-1 ]**

which is the desired ordering i want

the ordering becomes

**[1, 1-1, 1-2, 10,10-1, 3,4 ]**

how can i fix that?

Comment: Is the tag attribute a string?

Comment: ah yes, is that the problem?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski thank you for reply. Now i understand what happens. Is there a way to "fix" the issue without changing tag type in db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `tag` is a string and if you order strings `ASC` you order them **alphabetically**. You'll have to write a custom method to sort records by.

Let's say your sort method is called `order_by_tag`. Then you can order your categories like so: `Category.all.sort_by(&:order_by_tag)`.

Note that this is more difficult if you don't want to iterate over a large number of records every time.

To write a custom sorting method, you'll have to come up with a way to calculate a **value** of your tag. You could do something like this:

```
def order_by_tag
  tag.split('-').reverse.each_with_index.map do |tag, index| 
    tag.to_i * 2**(index + 1) }
  end.reduce(:+) # => 1*(2^1) + 10*(2^2) = 42
end
```

Or, shorter:

```
def order_by_tag
  tag.split('-').reverse.each_with_index.map { |tag, index| tag.to_i * 2**(index + 1) }.reduce(:+) # => 1*(2^1) + 10*(2^2) = 42
end
```

But this example assumes a limit on a possible tag value.

**EDIT:**

There is an easier way. You can sort records by multiple attributes, if you return an array:

```
def order_by_tag
  tag.split('-').map { |t| t.to_i } # "10-1" => [10, 1]
end
```

This way Rails will sort records by the first member of the array, then the second and so forth. This way is **much better** than my first example because it's much easier and values of your categories won't overlap.

**SUMMARY:**

```
@categories = Category.all.sort_by(&:order_by_tag)

def order_by_tag
  tag.split('-').map { |t| t.to_i }
end
```

Comment: I just provided an example.

Comment: Please check an example provided in my latest edit. It's much better than the first one.

Comment: thank you very much for this, your efforts are appreciated!

Comment: I'm glad that I helped you!